# Bootstrap 3 popover hides instantly in Chrome for Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with the popovers of Bootstrap 3. Everywhere they are working and showing as it should, except for Chrome in both Mac and Windows. What happens is that when I invoke the show, really fast after that it hides, although it shouldn't.

The problem is actually when I try to use different placement than "right". Here is stripped down version of the code:

```
jQuery(selector).popover({trigger: "manual", placement: "left"}).popover("show");

<button id="popover" class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-lg" data-content="some text" data-ng-click="showPopover('#popover')">Popover</button>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://bootply.com/90720 (Chrome:  30.0.1599.101)

Comment: Yes, this one does work, but for some reason on my application it doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue and it turns out to be a conflict with jQuery Mobile's CSS. Apparently they have similar fade animations and it was looping. I disabled it and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. However, do you have a suggestion how this can be avoided and keep using both? Currently as a workaround I have to override few CSS styles and insert custom html, which in my opinion is not a very suitable solution.